# Set default field value, when category is deleted

Tags: python, django-models

I have two models, which are connected one to many:

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Dishes(models.Model):
    ...
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='No category')
    ...
```

I was expecting on_delete argument will set default (No category) value for column named "category" in the Dishes db, but it tried to change all the columns in the Categories db, so i got "ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'No category'." How can i change all the "categories" fields in Dishes db when category is deleted?

Edited after an answer. When i try to delete a category an error occurres. Traceback:

```
 File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 688, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1983, in changelist_view
    response = self.response_action(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1593, in response_action
    response = func(self, request, queryset)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\actions.py", line 51, in delete_selected
    modeladmin.delete_queryset(request, queryset)
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1237, in delete_queryset
    queryset.delete()
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1148, in delete
    deleted, _rows_count = collector.delete()
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py", line 506, in delete
    count = query.delete_batch(pk_list, self.using)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\subqueries.py", line 42, in delete_batch
    num_deleted += self.do_query(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\subqueries.py", line 20, in do_query
    cursor = self.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(CURSOR)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1549, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1895, in as_sql
    if self.single_alias and not self.contains_self_reference_subquery:
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\main\Django\website\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1878, in contains_self_reference_subquery
    self.query.control_types.values(), self.query.where.children
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that: the value is supposed to be a value of the field of the model the `ForeignKey` is referencing to, in this case that will be the primary key, and the primary key is likely an `AutoField`, hence an integer. But even if it was a `CharField`, that would mean such `Category` should existing with that value.

Likely it is better to work with a NULLable column, set it to null and add some property that returns the category or the string:

```
from django.contrib import admin


class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)


class Dish(models.Model):
    # …
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, default=None
    )

    @property
    @admin.display(description='category name')
    def category_name(self):
        category = self.category
        if category is None:
            return 'No category'
        return str(category)
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Category` instead of <s>`Categories`</s>.

Comment: Thanks, but when i try to delete category it raises an error: 'DeleteQuery' object has no attribute 'control_types'. How can i fix this one?

Comment: @Doule_: do you have any model with something as `control_types`? Can you edit the question with the full traceback?

Comment: I have only these two mentioned models

Comment: I've added the traceback. Could you have a look at that please?